# ForkJoinPool.invoke(task) vs invokeAll(task1)

Tags: java, fork-join

I am kind of confuse as to when should we be using `ForkJoinPool.invoke(task)` or `invokeAll(task1)`.

I understand the definition  for each but may I ask if anyone can give an example of how it works and when should i be using each of them for which scenario?

Thanks

Comment: There is a difference in execution. `invoke(...)` will block until computation is done, whereas `invokeAll(...)` will not block (thus returning a `List<Future<T>>`). However, to only submit a single task and not wait on the result (aka. obtain a `Future<T>`), one should call [`submit(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Do you mean that invokeAll(...) is similar to submit(..) where both of them are not blocking but invokeAll(...) submits multiple task?

Comment: From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-): "Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list."